# ASP.NET Core Claims not being fetched properly

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm building an app in ASP.NET Core 3.1 with Entity Framework Core 3.1 and am having some trouble debugging Authorization. Currently, I'm working on Claims-Based Authorization, as the code samples below will illustrate.

In the AdminController:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> EditUser(string id)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

        if (user == null)
            return RedirectToAction("UserManagement", _userManager.Users);

        var claims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);

        var vm = new EditUserViewModel()
        {
            Id = user.Id,
            UserClaims = claims.Select(c => c.Value).ToList(),
            Email = user.Email,
            UserName = user.UserName,
            Birthdate = user.Birthdate,
            City = user.City,                
            Country = user.Country

        };

        return View(vm);
    }
```

This function is called when I click on the Edit button next to a user in the Admin section of the app. The problem I'm having lies with the claims. I have the ability to add claims to a user, but somewhere in the code it isn't working correctly. When debugging, everything seems to work, and the database table AspNetUserClaims does contain the correct data after adding the claim to the user, but the function above has a bug in it that I'll try to describe.

Basically, on the EditUser View page, there should be an HTML ul of all claims the current user has. Even after adding claims to the user, though, no ul of claims displays. When debugging, I found that the problem seems to be in the EditUser code above, because the var claims is set to Count=0 after calling GetClaimsAsync(user). This value of Count=0 is then passed to the EditUserViewModel and set to the List property UserClaims. But Count=0 isn't any legitimate value, and I'm not sure where GetClaimsAsync(user) is getting that Count=0 from. As I said, the database table seems to be storing the data correctly.

If you need any more code or further details, be sure to let me know so I can make things easier to understand.

Comment: _"var claims is set to Count=0 after calling GetClaimsAsync(user)."_  I tested the code but there is no error and it get the claim list with the userId. Make sure that  the userId of the query has been added the corresponding claim list.

Comment: For some reason, my AspNetUserClaims table has both a column UserId and a column ApplicationUserId. The userId is only stored in the ApplicationUserId column, but the GetClaimsAsync(user) method pulls the data stored in the UserId column. When I manually copied the data in the ApplicationUserId column and pasted it into the UserId column, then everything works fine, just as it does for you. Do you know how I can automatically have the app store the same id data in both the ApplicationUserId and UserId columns?